# Mathematical operation between two columns in a comparison

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We're using Oracle 10g XE and we found that the following query didn't return any value:

```
SELECT ref.referencia,
       ref.descripcio,
       stock_reservat,
       stock,
       stock_p_rebre,
       (SELECT count(*)
          FROM ref_numeros_serie num
          WHERE num.empresa=ref.empresa AND
                num.referencia=ref.referencia AND
                num.diposit=1 AND
                nvl(num.actiu,'N')='S') cnt_nums_serie
  FROM emp_referencies ref,
       ref_stk_dip_acu stk
  WHERE ref.empresa=1 AND
        ref.referencia='1B' AND
        stk.empresa=ref.empresa AND
        stk.referencia=ref.referencia AND
        stk.diposit=1 AND
        -- Relevant part
        (stk.stock - stk.stock_reservat) <> (SELECT count(*)
                                             FROM ref_numeros_serie num
                                             WHERE num.empresa=ref.empresa AND 
                                                   num.referencia=ref.referencia AND 
                                                   num.diposit=1 AND 
                                                   nvl(num.actiu,'N')='S') 
        -- End of relevant part
  GROUP BY ref.empresa,
           ref.referencia,
           ref.descripcio,
           stk.stock,
           stk.stock_reservat,
           stock,
           stock_p_rebre
```

So the comparison between the subtraction and the subquery was false. But if we swapped the subquery and the subtraction like this:

```
SELECT ref.referencia,ref.descripcio,
       stock_reservat,
       stock, 
       stock_p_rebre,
       (SELECT count(*)
          FROM ref_numeros_serie num
          WHERE num.empresa=ref.empresa AND
                num.referencia=ref.referencia AND
                num.diposit=1 AND
                nvl(num.actiu,'N')='S') cnt_nums_serie
  FROM emp_referencies ref,
       ref_stk_dip_acu stk
  WHERE ref.empresa=1 AND
        ref.referencia='1B' AND
        stk.empresa=ref.empresa AND
        stk.referencia=ref.referencia AND
        stk.diposit=1 AND
        -- Relevant part
        (SELECT count(*)
           FROM ref_numeros_serie num
           WHERE num.empresa=ref.empresa AND
                 num.referencia=ref.referencia AND
                 num.diposit=1 AND
                 nvl(num.actiu,'N')='S') <> (stk.stock - stk.stock_reservat)
        -- End of relevant part
  GROUP BY ref.empresa,
           ref.referencia,
           ref.descripcio,
           stk.stock,
           stk.stock_reservat,
           stock,
           stock_p_rebre
```

The comparison is true and we get results.

We have tried the following cases:

- Removing the second part of the subtraction so the left part of the comparison is `stk.stock`: we get results, correct
- Changing the second part of the subtraction by a number like this `stk.stock-2`: we get results, correct
- Swapping the left and right part of the comparison, as explained above: we get results, correct
- Changing the arithmetic operator like this `(stk.stock+stk.stock_reservat) <> subquery`: no results, incorrect
- Changing the subquery by a number like this `(stk.stock-stk.stock_reservat) <> 2`: we get results, correct

We have tried these cases with a 10g non-XE database and it has the same behaviour. With a 11g, on the other hand, it works perfectly fine.

So our conclusion is that with oracle 10g a comparison between an arithmetic operation between two columns and a subquery works only if the subquery is on the left side and the operation on the right side. Has anybody had a similar problem and how did you work around/fix it?

EDIT: I want to add that this happens when the subquery result is 0, we haven't had issues with it otherwise, i.e. it behaves as expected.

Comment: Try changing `(stk.stock - stk.stock_reservat)` to `(stk.stock - NVL(stk.stock_reservat, 0))` and see if that helps. Share and enjoy.

Comment: We have tried that and it didn't work

Comment: Are you up-to-date on all patches? I recall that 10g had problems and, as you've noticed, 11 is a lot more stable.

Answer (score 0):

Your query could be simplified by using a subquery factoring clause, as in:

```
WITH ns AS (SELECT r.empresa, r.referencia, count(*) as CNT_NUMS_SERIE
              FROM ref_numeros_serie n
              INNER JOIN emp_referencies r
                r.empresa = n.empresa AMD
                r.referencia = n.referencia 
              WHERE n.diposit = 1 AND
                    NVL(n.actiu, 'N') = 'S'
              GROUP BY r.empresa,
                       r.referencia)
SELECT ref.referencia,
       ref.descripcio,
       stock_reservat,
       stock,
       stock_p_rebre,
       ns.CNT_NUMS_SERIE
  FROM emp_referencies ref
  INNER JOIN ref_stk_dip_acu stk
    ON stk.empresa = ref.empresa AND
       stk.referencia = ref.referencia
  INNER JOIN ns
    ON ns.empresa = ref.empresa AND
       ns.referencia = ref.referencia
  WHERE ref.empresa = 1 AND
        ref.referencia = '1B' AND
        stk.diposit = 1 AND
        -- Relevant part
        (stk.stock - NVL(stk.stock_reservat, 0)) <> ns.CNT_NUMS_SERIE
        -- End of relevant part
  GROUP BY ref.empresa,
           ref.referencia,
           ref.descripcio,
           stk.stock,
           stk.stock_reservat,
           stock,
           stock_p_rebre
```

This lets you pull the common expression (`SELECT COUNT(*)...`) out and treat it as a separate table. I think it makes the query easier to read and might save some execution time.

Share and enjoy.